# CMD.exe has premonitions about variable values

Tags: batch-file, windows-7-x64, cmd

I'm getting strange behavior in variable assignment in a batch script that I've written. The simplest example I could concoct to re-create the problem follows. I created the file `type pos.bat`:

```
@echo on
FOR /R ".\" %%F IN (*.txt) DO (
echo Look: %%F
set file=%%~dpF%%~nF
echo %file%
)
```

In a directory containing two *.txt files, with one in a subdirectory:

```
pos/
    |-pos.bat
    |-file1.txt
    |dir/
         |-file2.txt
```

I get the following output:

```
F:\pos>pos.bat
F:\pos>FOR /R ".\" %F IN (*.txt) DO (
echo Look: %F
 set file=%~dpF%~nF
 echo F:\pos\dir\file2
)

F:\pos>(
echo Look: F:\pos\file1.txt
 set file=F:\pos\file1
 echo F:\pos\dir\file2
)
Look: F:\pos\file1.txt
F:\pos\dir\file2

F:\pos>(
echo Look: F:\pos\dir\file2.txt
 set file=F:\pos\dir\file2
 echo F:\pos\dir\file2
)
Look: F:\pos\dir\file2.txt
F:\pos\dir\file2
```

Shouldn't the value of `%file%` change back to `F:\pos\file1.txt` on the first iteration of the loop? Also, I was surprised that the value of `%file% should persist at all between calls to the script. The first call to the script behaved as I intended:

```
F:\pos>FOR /R ".\" %F IN (*.txt) DO (
echo Look: %F
 set file=%~dpF%~nF
 echo
)

F:\pos>(
echo Look: F:\pos\file1.txt
 set file=F:\pos\file1
 echo
)
Look: F:\pos\file1.txt
ECHO is on.

F:\pos>(
echo Look: F:\pos\dir\file2.txt
 set file=F:\pos\dir\file2
 echo
)
Look: F:\pos\dir\file2.txt
ECHO is on.
```

But all subsequent calls give me garbage results. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable delayed expansion and then use `!` for the variable within the loop.

**At the top of your file (typically)**

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
```

**Within your FOR loop**

```
echo !file!
```

Here's a [good resource](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) on the why's and wherefore's.